# span and querySelector

Tags: javascript, html

I think my question is very easy but I am very new to javascript.
I have a code that takes information from HTMl code with queryselector.
The code of javascript is this:

```
  userData.innerHTML = resp.responseText;
              if(userData.querySelector('strong.username a')) {
                username = userData.querySelector('strong.username a').textContent;
              }
```

The code in the HTML page is this:

```
<span class="name-of-thumb">        
<a href="/houses/palo">North Carolina</a>
</span>
```

I need to use querySelector to get "North Carolina" from HTML. How should I modify the part "strong.username a" in the javascript code?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

`span.name-of-thumb a` will work, or just `.name-of-thumb a`.  That will select the first `a` node that is found with the `.name-of-thumb` parent.

Comment: Thank you very much!!! Sorry if it was easy question but I really didn't know how to do, but you explained well. Thank you!

Comment: Be aware that using the `.name-of-thumb a` version will find the FIRST occurrence of ANY element with class `name-of-thumb` which has an `a` element. This may or may not be what you want.